# azure functions free tier within 12 month trial

Tags: azure-functions, azure-billing

What if I exceed azure functions free tier within the 12 month trial?
Will it charge after exceeding limits and is there way to set hard limit on budget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the free tier, you have these services for free and for more details, check this [MicrosoftFAQ](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/free-account-faq/) regarding what is the maximum usage of each service within the free tier.

For example,  within the free tier (12 months) to Azure Functions

> 1 million requests and 4,00,000 GBs of resource consumption with [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/functions/)

---

> Will it charge after exceeding limits?

Azure Free Account/Subscription provides the 200$ Credit in billing currency which has validity of 30 days & 12 months of some free services. It means, after 30 days - the Azure Subscription is **disabled** to protect from **accidentally charges incurring** if the subscription is used beyond the credit.

After you [upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/upgrade-azure-subscription), your subscription has 12 months free services + charged for usage beyond the free service quantity limits.

For more details like how to upgrade to pay-as-you-go subscription, how to reactivate any subscription if cancelled accidentally, refer to this [cost-management-billing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/subscription-disabled)

---

> is there way to set hard limit on budget?

Yes, we can set the hard limit on budget using cost alerts option to every resource in the Azure.

1. Click on any resource and select Cost Alerts option under cost management group in left index of your resource page in Azure portal.
2. And define the scope, cost limit, alert mail, time period. After defining, you can see the detailed graph like this:

[image]

To know "How to keep budget/cost alert for every resource", refer this [Microsoft documentation for cost-mgt-alerts-monitor-usage-spending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/cost-mgt-alerts-monitor-usage-spending)

---

> What will happen if I got ddos

Azure's infrastructure DDoS (Basic) Protection is available to all properties in Azure at no additional cost.
[image]

There are 2 kinds in Azure DDoS: Basic and Standard.

DDoS Protection Basic doesn't need user configuration adjustments. All Azure services, such as PaaS services like Azure DNS, are protected with the aid of DDoS Protection Basic.

In conjunction with best practices for application architecture, Azure DDoS Protection Standard offers improved DDoS mitigation options to stop DDoS attacks.

For more details on how to use Azure DDoS Protection with 5-minute [quick start tutorials and documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/ddos-protection/#get-started)

To see the pricing options, how to purchase and where to purchase - Refer this [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/ddos-protection/) gives you clear idea about pricing details.

Comment: What will happen if I got ddos

Comment: updated the answer regarding the ddos. In a brief, we get azure DDoS basic without user configuration to every azure property in a free tier, but in order to upgrade it i have given pricing details link and features of standard protection details link in the answer. Please check and let me know if any additional details required!